# Error compiling CJK with \tableofcontents and \makeindex

Tags: table-of-contents, errors, indexing, cjk

A basic document with Chinese text works fine:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{CJKutf8}
\title{标题}
\begin{document}
    \begin{CJK}{UTF8}{gkai}
        \maketitle
        (text)
    \end{CJK}
\end{document}
```

When I add a table of contents and 1 section with Chinese text, it does not compile:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{CJKutf8}
\begin{document}
    \begin{CJK}{UTF8}{gkai}
        \tableofcontents
        \section{第一章}
        (text)
    \end{CJK}
\end{document}
```

> Package inputenc Error: Unicode char \u 8:第 not set up for use with LaTeX.

When I create an index entry with Chinese text, it also does not compile:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{CJKutf8}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex
\begin{document}
    \begin{CJK}{UTF8}{gkai}
        (text) \index{nihao@ 你好 nihao}
        \printindex
    \end{CJK}
\end{document}
```

> ! Package inputenc Error: Unicode char \u 8:你 not set up for use with LaTeX.
>
> See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.
>   Type  H   for immediate help.
>    ...
>
> l.3 ...reak or    to continue without it.}
>                                                     \GenericError  {(inputenc)...

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From package documentation `CJKutf8.txt`:

> If you get the error message: `` `\CJK... undefined' `` or other `` `... undefined ...' `` messages and you can't find an error, try inserting
>           `\newpage`, `\clearpage`, or `\cleardoublepage` (the latter for two-column
>           printing) before saying `\end{CJK}` or `\end{CJK*}`. This can happen if
>           LaTeX 2e writes headers, footers, or index entries (both \index and
>           `\printindex`) of a page containing CJK characters after closing the
>           CJK environment.
>   ...
>
> A similar error message from CJKutf8.sty (with the same solution) is
>
> ```
> Package inputenc Error:
> Unicode char \u 8: XXX not set up for use with LaTeX
> ```

So adding a `\clearpage` just before `\end{CJK}` in your code worked for me.

Alternatively, consider using the `ctex` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[UTF8]{ctex}

\begin{document}
        \tableofcontents
        \section{第一章}
        (text)
\end{document}
```

Or use `xeCJK` with XeLaTeX:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xeCJK}
\setCJKmainfont{STSong}

\begin{document}
        \tableofcontents
        \section{第一章}
        (text)
\end{document}
```

Comment: `ctex` package just simply add a `\clearpage` before `\end{CJK*}`. It is an old bug of `CJK` package for years and we have nothing more to do.