# CJK in todonotes

Tags: pdftex, cjk, todonotes

tl;dr: I am looking for a way to put small CJK text snippets in an otherwise English text inside todonotes and into the list of todos, without disrupting my existing large document too much in pdftex.

Now the long story: 
I am trying to put CJK text in a todonote. Usually, if I just want a little snippet of CJK text, I input it like this:

```
\begin{CJK}{UTF8}{gkai}木\protect\end{CJK}
```

But used inside a todonote this said

```
! Argument of \reserved@a has an extra }.
! Paragraph ended before \reserved@a was complete.
```

After searching around a bit, I found I needed to protect the CJK-environment. This worked fine as long as I did not want a `\listoftodos`. So I ended up with this MNWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{extreport}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos, textwidth=\marginparwidth]{todonotes}
\usepackage{CJKutf8}

\begin{document}
\listoftodos
\todo{\protect\begin{CJK}{UTF8}{gkai}木\protect\end{CJK}}

\end{document}
```

This however now throws the error:

```
! Package inputenc Error: Unicode char \u 8:木 not set up for use with LaTeX.
```

Even though the `\begin{CJK}` end `\end{CJK}`  are in the `.tdo` file.

```
\contentsline {todo}{\color@box {}{orange}{\leavevmode {\color {orange}o}}\ 
\begin {CJK}{UTF8}{gkai}\GenericError {(inputenc) }{
 Package inputenc Error: Unicode char \u 8:木 not set up for use with LaTeX}{
 See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.}{
 Your command was ignored.
 \MessageBreak Type I <command> <return> to replace it with another command,
 \MessageBreak or <return> to continue without it.}
 \end {CJK}}{1}
```

Is there any way to get this to work without using xelatex? I found [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/34108/39366) question, where the answer seemed to be to use `\clearpage` before the `\end{CJK}`, but if I do that inside a todonote, I get

```
! Paragraph ended before \@dottedtocline was complete.
```

and the other variant, using `\usepackage[UTF8]{ctex}` instead of `\usepackage{CJKutf8}` worked in my MWE, but did not work in the rather large file that I actually want to use this in, throwing a

```
tex capacity exceeded
```

error that I do not understand. So, I am out of ideas now and would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to hide it in a robust command (which you need to define before the notes list at the start of the document)

[image]

[You would need to delete any corrupt `.tdo` file from previous attempts)

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{extreport}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos, textwidth=\marginparwidth]{todonotes}
\usepackage{CJKutf8}

\begin{document}
\DeclareRobustCommand\tdone{\begin{CJK}{UTF8}{gkai}木\protect\end{CJK}}

\listoftodos

\todo{\tdone}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I was experimenting with `\DeclareRobustCommand` at some point, but I never got it quite right, apparently. But now it works :)